# Sweetalert 2 textarea async

Tags: jquery, sweetalert2

I tried with this simple example of documentation https://sweetalert2.github.io/ but i get the error message :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.buttonproblem').click(function() {
    const { value : text } = await swal({
      input: 'textarea',
      inputPlaceholder: 'Type your message here',
      showCancelButton: true
    })

    if (text) {
      swal(text)
    }
  })   
});
```

Comment: but i used the example of the doc and its working ? https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: Could you please link to the documentation that shows this usage pattern

Comment: Why do you need await and async for showing a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you need to declare the `click` handler function as `async` in order to use the `await` keyword within it. Try this:

```js
$('.buttonproblem').click(async function() { // note use of 'async' here
  const text = await swal({
    title: 'foo', // Note this was missing in your example
    input: 'textarea',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Type your message here',
    showCancelButton: true
  })

  if (text) {
    swal(text)
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<button class="buttonproblem">Click me</button>
```

Note that your `const { value:  text }` syntax was causing an error, although the logic worked fine, so I removed it.

Comment: I amended your answer to use https://sweetalert2.github.io/ It's different from https://sweetalert.js.org/