# SweetAlert2 : Executing "function" or "async function" based on selection of a div after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, promise, sweetalert2

Right now, what happens is the following:

1. When clicking a button in the middle, five circles show up.

2. When you click a circle, a popup message made with SweetAlert2 shows up.

3. When clicking the "ok" button in the popup message, the message is closed and you can see that the circle's background was changed to light orange.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694178/including-a-different-image-in-sweetalert2-popup-message-based-on-selection-of-a), [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) let me know how to execute different SweetAlert function.
His solution was using `if($(this).attr('id')!="option5")` and `else` within `.on("click", function(){}`. (jsFiddle for his solution can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/15no3zyd/5/)).
His solution worked for choosing among functions that did not require `async`. 
By the way, I got curious about executing "function" or "async function" based on selection of a div after clicking a button and he advised me to ask another question. I asked him about this, and he advised me to add a question. So, I am posting this!
**What I want to do** : show a popup message that require user-input only when clicking a circle with the text "okay".
**The challenge** : The current SweetAlert2 message starts with `click: function(){`and the popup message I would like to include starts with `click: async function(){`.

*Note*: I assigned "options" class for all circles and different id for each circle. The id for a circle with the text "okay" is "option5".
I'd greatly appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#fallingStars").delay(300).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
    $("#title").delay(500).animate({'opacity':'1'},800);
    $("#slogan").delay(800).animate({'opacity':'1'},800);

    // https://codepen.io/hlim18/pen/EpbLmN
    $('#test').click(function(){
        // $(".options").fadeToggle();
        $(".options:hidden").fadeIn()
            .on("click", function(){
                // hex color #_ _ _ _ _ _
                $(this).css("background", "#F3C78D");
            })
            .on({
                click: function(){
                   swal({
                     title: 'Sweet!',
                     text: 'Modal with a custom image.',
                     imageUrl: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200',
                     imageWidth: 400,
                     imageHeight: 200,
                     imageAlt: 'Custom image',
                     animation: false
                  })
                  
                // click: async function(){

                // // // "text" enter message START
                // const {value: text} = await swal({
                //     title: 'Why do you feel unsafe here?',
                //     input: 'text',
                //     inputPlaceholder: 'Type your message :)',
                //     customClass: 'swal2-textbox-msg',

                //     showCancelButton: true,
                //     confirmButtonColor: '#F3C78D',
                //     confirmButtonText: '<div id="swal2-confirmBtnTxt" style="color:#000000">Yes!</div>',
                //     cancelButtonColor: '#9FEDDA',
                //     cancelButtonText: '<div id="swal2-cancelBtnTxt" style="color:#000000">Cancel</div>',
                //     // backdrop color : light gray
                //     backdrop: `
                //     rgba(211,211,211,0.4) 
                //     center left
                //     no-repeat
                //     `,
                //     inputValidator: (value) => {
                //         return !value && 'You need to write something!'
                //     }
                // });
                // if (text) {
                //     swal({
                //         text: `Your entered : "${text}"`,
                //         // backdrop color : light gray
                //         backdrop: `
                //         rgba(211,211,211,0.4) 
                //         center left
                //         no-repeat
                //         `,
                //         confirmButtonColor: '#F3C78D',
                //         confirmButtonText: '<div id="swal2-confirmBtnTxt" style="color:#000000">Okay</div>'
                //     })
                // }
            }
        });
    });     
})
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Poor Story', sans-serif;
}

#test{
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.options {
    background: #f7f7f5;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #F3C78D;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.options span {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#option1{
    transform: translate(-100%, -150%);
}

#option2{
    transform: translate(-160%, -40%);
}

#option3{
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

#option4{
    transform: translate(60%, -40%);
}

#option5{
    transform: translate(15%, -150%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!-- [Google Fonts] To embed your selected fonts into a webpage, copy this code into the <head> of your HTML document. -->
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sunflower:300" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poor+Story" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.0 : jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <!-- sweetalert2 -->
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="test">test</button>
    <div class="options" id="option1"><span>Hello<br>World</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option2"><span>Goodbye</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option3"><span>How<br>are<br>you?</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option4"><span>Fine</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option5"><span>Okay</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is that second function asynchronous if it's an event listener?

Comment: I wanted to use the textbox popup message that required user input on the SweetAlert2 official webpage(https://sweetalert2.github.io/#position) and couldn't make it work. I got "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function" error. So, I searched the issue on StackOverflow and found out that I needed to include "async" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751053/sweetalert-2-textarea-async). The accepted answer says, "The issue is because you need to declare the click handler function as async in order to use the await keyword within it."

Comment: if `await` works on `swal` then `swal` is a promise and you can just use something like `swal(...).then(function({value}=> { ///run code here } )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! I assigned "withoutInput" class for options 1~4 and "withInput" class for option 5.

- To have multiple classes, put a space between the classes. For example, to have `class apple` and `class orange` together, you can write as `class="apple orange"`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // https://codepen.io/hlim18/pen/EpbLmN
    $('#test').click(function(){
        // $(".options").fadeToggle();
        $(".withoutInput:hidden").fadeIn()
            .on("click", function(){
                // hex color #_ _ _ _ _ _
                $(this).css("background", "#F3C78D");
            })
            .on({
                // // include this for "thank-you" & "cancel" message codes
                click: function(){
                // // "Thank-you" message START
                    swal({
                        title: 'Thank you!',
                        text: 'Your input has been recorded.',
                        // type: 'warning',
                        imageUrl: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200', 
                        imageAlt: 'Unsplash',
                        // imageClass: 'swal2-thx-img',
                        animation: false,
                        customClass: 'swal2-thx-msg',
                        // backdrop color : light gray
                        backdrop: `
                            rgba(211,211,211,0.4) 
                            center left
                            no-repeat
                        `,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#9FEDDA',
                        confirmButtonText: '<div id="swal2-confirmBtnTxt" style="color:#000000">Got it!</div>'
                    })
                }
                // // "click: function" END
                // // "Thank-you" message END

            });
            // "withoutInput" END
        $(".withInput:hidden").fadeIn()
            .on("click", function(){
                // hex color #_ _ _ _ _ _
                $(this).css("background", "#F3C78D");
            })
            .on({
                // include this for "text-input" & "login & password" message codes
                click: async function(){

                    // // // "text" enter message START
                    const {value: text} = await swal({
                        title: 'Why do you feel unsafe here?',
                        input: 'text',
                        inputPlaceholder: 'Type your message :)',
                        customClass: 'swal2-textbox-msg',

                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#F3C78D',
                        confirmButtonText: '<div id="swal2-confirmBtnTxt" style="color:#000000">Yes!</div>',
                        cancelButtonColor: '#9FEDDA',
                        cancelButtonText: '<div id="swal2-cancelBtnTxt" style="color:#000000">Cancel</div>',
                        // backdrop color : light gray
                        backdrop: `
                        rgba(211,211,211,0.4) 
                        center left
                        no-repeat
                        `,
                        inputValidator: (value) => {
                            return !value && 'You need to write something!'
                        }
                    });
                    if (text) {
                        swal({
                            text: `Your entered : "${text}"`,
                            // backdrop color : light gray
                            backdrop: `
                            rgba(211,211,211,0.4) 
                            center left
                            no-repeat
                            `,
                            confirmButtonColor: '#F3C78D',
                            confirmButtonText: '<div id="swal2-confirmBtnTxt" style="color:#000000">Okay</div>'
                        })
                    }
                // // "text" enter message END
                }
                // // async msg END
            });
            // // "withInput" END
    });   
})
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Poor Story', sans-serif;
}

#test{
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.options {
    background: #f7f7f5;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #F3C78D;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.options span {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#option1{
    transform: translate(-100%, -150%);
}

#option2{
    transform: translate(-160%, -40%);
}

#option3{
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

#option4{
    transform: translate(60%, -40%);
}

#option5{
    transform: translate(15%, -150%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!-- [Google Fonts] To embed your selected fonts into a webpage, copy this code into the <head> of your HTML document. -->
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sunflower:300" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poor+Story" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.0 : jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <!-- sweetalert2 -->
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="test">test</button>
    <div class="options withoutInput" id="option1"><span>Hello<br>World</span></div>
    <div class="options withoutInput" id="option2"><span>Goodbye</span></div>
    <div class="options withoutInput" id="option3"><span>How<br>are<br>you?</span></div>
    <div class="options withoutInput" id="option4"><span>Fine</span></div>
    <div class="options withInput" id="option5"><span>Okay</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's the link to the JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hlim188/15no3zyd/30/